# Thread abort after handling a POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

So this application runs seamlessly in Visual Studio, but I have created an installer for the program in which the error is encountered. I think I have pinned down what the issue is. When a POST is received it is handled which kicks off a separate decoupled process which eventually gets aborted from the webpage disposing/closing.

The program flow is such

- POST received `context.Request.HttpMethod == "POST"`,
- pertinent xml info extracted and written to disk,
- `csfireEyeHandler.DonJobOnLastIp()`,
- a monitor running in the background picks up on the file creation event `void OnChanged' and starts running services based on the XML doc
- `FileAdded` --> `readerRef.ReadInServices(e.FullPath, false)`.

The problem is after the POST is handled it causes the services to abort with the ThreadAbortException.  If a delay is placed after `handler.ProcessRequest(context)` the services finish, I presume because the page still open. I cannot figure out how to properly handle this situation, its terribly difficult to debug because I cannot get the error to occur in VS.

```
public partial class fireEye : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = Context;
        fireEyeHandler handler = new fireEyeHandler();
        handler.ProcessRequest(context);          
    }
}

public class fireEyeHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            var extension = context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split('/')[2].ToLower();

            var stream = context.Request.InputStream;
            var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            var xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

            FileManage.WriteToFile(xml, @"C:\ECC_output\fireEye.xml");
            var csfireEyeHandler = new FireEyeService { config = extension + ".config" };

            csfireEyeHandler.Load();
            csfireEyeHandler.DonJobOnLastIp();

            context.Response.StatusCode = 202;              
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}

public class Monitor
{
    bool monitorIsActive;
    readonly XmlRead readerRef;  // Reference to the xml reader
    readonly FileSystemWatcher watch;
    public bool monitorRunning;

    public Monitor(XmlRead reader)
    {
        watch = new FileSystemWatcher();
        readerRef = reader;

        try
        {
            watch.Path = @"C:\ECC_temp"; //directory to monitor
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            Report.LogLine (ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        watch.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        watch.Filter = "*.xml";
        monitorIsActive = true;

        watch.Created += OnChanged;
        watch.Deleted += OnChanged;
        watch.Renamed += OnRenamed;

        watch.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Toggles on/off if a directory is being monitored
    /// </summary>
    public void ToggleMonitor()
    {
        monitorIsActive = !monitorIsActive;
        var monitorState = monitorIsActive ? "on" : "false";

        Report.LogLine ("Monitor is " + monitorState);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// File has been added to the directory
    /// </summary>
    public bool FileAdded(FileSystemEventArgs e, XmlDocument xmlDocument)
    {
        try
        {
            var date = string.Format ("<br>\r\n**********************Report  {0:yyyy MM-dd hh:mm tt}**********************", DateTime.Now);
            Report.LogLine(date);

            readerRef.Validate(e.FullPath, false);
            readerRef.ReadInServices(e.FullPath, false);

            Report.CreateReport();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Report.LogLine(exception.Message + " id:6");
            Report.CreateReport();
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When a file is added, renamed or deleted, OnChanged is called and the appropriate action is taken
    /// </summary>
    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        monitorRunning = true;
        while (true)
        {
            if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created || e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Renamed)
            {
                var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                try
                {                        
                    xmlDocument.Load(e.FullPath);
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }

                if (FileAdded(e, xmlDocument))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        monitorRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your application knows about this Monitor and knows how to detect that its currently handling a file change event and not return from the post, there's nothing you can do.  I would suggest not coupling the web application to this Monitor (you haven't explained its purpose).  I would suggest pulling it out of the web application and putting it in a Windows service of some sort.  Or, explain in more detail why this Monitor is in the web application.

Comment: The web app knows nothing about the Monitor. The Monitor initiates services from xml files being dropped into a directory. I assumed that since they had no reference to each other that one could not cause the other to terminate, but that is not the case. I am going to try to move the FireEye handler to a MVCcontroller so that it does not live within a webpage that disposes.

Comment: I don't think moving this around will benefit you much.  I believe you have a fundamental design problem here.  You have something in the background that's busy trying to read files while you have something else busy trying to read or write to those same files.  Either you have to make your file watcher handlers back off a bit and let the other code finish, or have some way of signalling code that a create has occurred and all the writing is complete.

Comment: I honestly don't think a file system watcher is the right solution for this; you can add a pause after the notification of a create; but whatever time you pick to pause will always be wrong.  It's all in the same process, why not just have the code that creates inform code that logs or does the reporting.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that `FileSystemWatcher` can fire as soon as the file is *created*, which can often be **while the ASP.NET process is still in the middle of writing the document**.

I'd expect this to cause an XML read exception, or an access denied exception however, not neccessarily a `ThreadAbort` exception. `ThreadAbort` exceptions usually only happen if someone calls `Thread.Abort`, which you should never, ever do.

Anyway, You can get around this by using [`System.IO.FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream) to write your file and tell windows to lock it while it's being written to.

- When you open the file to write it, specify `FileShare.None`. This will prevent the monitor from trying to read the file until the ASP.net process is done writing.
- In your Monitor, add a retry loop with a small sleep in it when opening the file. You should get an access denied exception (which I think will be an `IOException`) repeatedly until the file is ready for you to read.

I can't really help any more than that without understanding what your csFireEyeHandler thing is supposed to do. Are you expecting the monitor service to finish processing the file in the middle of your ASP.net request? This is unlikely to happen.

What I'd expect the workflow to be:

```
         ASP PAGE                     Monitor Process

     > File Uploaded                   |
     |                                 |
     > Begin Write to disk             |
     |                                 > Try open file
     |                                 > fail to read file and retry
     > Finish write to disk            |
     |                                 > open file
     |                                 | 
     |                                 > Begin process file
     > csFireEyeHandler.Load           |
     > csFireEyeHandler.DonJob         |
     > RETURN                          |
                                       |
                                       > Finish process file (Report.CreateReport)
```

If in fact you need the fireEyeHandler to wait for the background service, there are several ways you can do this... but why not just process the file in the fireEyeHandler?

Comment: Yes, that was an error I was dealing with earlier, I do catch the IOException and put the thread to sleep. The thread abortion is happening after `readerRef.Validate` at `readerRef.ReadInServices`. The validate method validates the created XMl against a schema and than runs the appropriate service delineated in the XML. It had nothing to do with the services though.

Comment: OK. At some point, someone must be calling `Thread.Abort`, or explicitly throwing a `ThreadAbortException`; you need to figure out who this is, and why they are doing it... I'd start with searching your code for any calls to Thread.Abort... Failing that, I'd set up some code to create a memory dump of the process, which you can then ship over to your debug PC and figure out what was going on.

Comment: Thread.Abort is likely being called by the ASP.NET subsystem after the end of the post command--usually when recycling the application.

Answer (score 0):

According to my interpretation of your question you don't want to wait until a file monitor event has occurred before you send the response to the client. You want to send 200 immediately and process in the background.

This is an anti-pattern in ASP.NET because the runtime does not guarantee that a worker process stays alive when all running HTTP requests have exited. In that sense, ASP.NET is conforming to the specification: It can abort your custom threads at any time.

It would be easier to get this right if you waited until the "service processing" is completed before sending 200 as an HTTP response.